# SQL query to select from one table based on a column value in other table

Tags: sql, join

I have two tables and I want to select all values from "TABLE A" that have a different value in  a column from "TABLE B".

I tried this

```
SELECT A.* FROM tableA A
left join tableB B  ON A.id = B.id WHERE B.column <> 1;
```

But this just return the value that I want to ignore.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT A.*
FROM tableA A
INNER JOIN tableB B
ON A.id = B.id
WHERE B.column != 1;
```

or

```
SELECT A.* FROM tableA A WHERE A.Id NOT IN (SELECT B.Id FROM tableB B WHERE B.column != 1)
```

Depends on your SQL you can use <> or !=

Comment: I did not explain myself well, I want to show every row from table A that his value in a specific column is not 1. I edit the question.

Comment: Thanks, I end up using Select * from local where local_id not in (select fk_local from table where text = 'Segundo') and column= 162. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest `not exists`:

```
SELECT A.*
FROM tableA A
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM tableB B WHERE A.id = B.id AND B.column = 1);
```

Using a `JOIN` can result in duplicated rows, if more than one row in `B` matches the `JOIN` condition.

Comment: Also it complicates things: join is joining something new, for filter in SQL you use where clause.

Comment: I did not explain myself well, I want to show every row from table A that his value in a specific column is not 1. I edit the question.

Comment: @luis . . . In that case, you want `not exists`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Thanks, I end up using Select * from local where local_id not in (select fk_local from table where text = 'Segundo') and column= 162. I'm not sure if "not in" works the same way. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @luis . . . `NOT IN` handles `NULL` values differently from `NOT EXISTS`, and also optimizes differently.  I strongly recommend using `NOT EXISTS` over `NOT IN`.